# JDK 7: Existing file gets empty on new File("path/to/file.html");

Tags: java, file-io, java-7

I'm using JDK 7. I've got a class with a method that creates a html-file using PrintStream. Another method in the same class is supposed to use the created file and do stuff with it. The problem is that once i use new File("path/to/file.html), the file lenght is reduced to 0. My code:

```
public class CreatePDFServiceImpl {

private final PrintStream printStream;

public CreatePDFServiceImpl() throws IOException {
    printStream = new PrintStream("/mnt/test.html", "UTF-8");
}

public void createHtmlFile() throws IncorporationException {
    try {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlFragments htmlFragments = new HtmlFragments();
        html.append(htmlFragments.getHtmlTop())
 .append(htmlFragments.getHeading())
 .append(htmlFragments.buildBody())
 .append(htmlFragments.buildFooter());
        printStream.print(html.toString());
    }  finally {
        if(printStream != null) {
            printStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This next method is supposed to use the html file created in "createHtmlFile()":

```
 public void convertHtmlToPdf() {
    PrintStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("/mnt/test.html");
        /** this code added just for debug **/
        if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists. size: " + file.length());
        }

        /* PDF generation commented out. */
        //out = new PrintStream("/mnt/testfs.pdf", "UTF-8");
        //defaultFileWriter.writeFile(file, out, iTextRenderer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IncorporationException("Could not save pdf file", e);
    } finally {
        if(out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

My junit integration test class:

```
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class CreatePDFServiceIntegrationTest {

private static CreatePDFServiceImpl createPDFService;

@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws IOException {
    createPDFService = new CreatePDFServiceImpl();
}

@Test
public void testCreateHtmlFile() throws IncorporationException {
    createPDFService.createHtmlFile();
    File createdFile = new File("/mnt/test.html");
    System.out.println("createdFile.length() = " + createdFile.length());
    Assert.assertTrue(createdFile.length() > 1);
}

@Test
public void testCreatePDF() throws Exception {
    File fileThatShouldExist = new File("/mnt/testfs.pdf");
    createPDFService.convertHtml2Pdf();

    Assert.assertTrue(fileThatShouldExist.exists());
}
}
```

The first test passes, output:

```
 "createdFile.length() = 3440".
```

I checked the file system, there is the file. size 3,44kb.

Second test fails, output from CreatePDFServiceImpl:

```
"File already exists. size: 0"
```

Looking in the file system, the file now is actually 0 bytes.

I'm stumped. The new File("path") should only create a reference to that file and not empty it?

Comment: You should use the method `exists()` instead of `createNewFile()` to check the presence of the file.

Comment: Make sure that you `flush()` your `PrintStream`.

Comment: I tried that too, same result. The createNewFile only creates a new file it does not already exist. In this case the file already existed, hence no new file was created.

Comment: Oliver, i added the printStream.flush() on the createHtmlMethod, but still same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there's an error in `File.createNewFile()`. I don't yet fully grasp in which order you run your code, but are you aware that this sets the file size to zero?

```
out = new PrintStream("/mnt/testfs.pdf", "UTF-8");
```

From the `PrintStream(File file)` Javadoc:

> file - The file to use as the destination of this print stream. If the
>   file exists, then **it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new
>   file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

I think that's the culprit - but in your code that line is commented out. Am I right you have run your tests with that line commented in?

Comment: The line could be commented. The `init` method of the test class calls the `CreatePDFServiceImpl` constructor. The constructor calls the `new PrintStream()` as well.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently running with the line commented out. Anyway, that line is not the same file (testfs.pdf not test.html). I'm creating an instance of the CreatePdfServiceImpl in the @BeforeClass, so the instance should be created just once in that test, hence the new PrintStream("mnt/test.html") should only be ran once.

Comment: also, the File.createNewFile() was added after i used if(file.exists()). Now I've changed back to if(file.exists()) and it has the same result...

Comment: But you are probably right, the error is related to the PrintStream. Tried creating the html-file, then commented out the html-method and test. Now the CreatePDFServiceImpl printed "File already exists. size: 3430".

Comment: It was the " new PrintStream("/mnt/test.html", "UTF-8");" in the constructor. Removed it and added if(printStream == null) {
                printStream = new PrintStream("/mnt/test.html", "UTF-8");
            } in the createHtmlFile() method. Now it works. Seems somehow the constructor is invoked before the testCreatePdf run. Might be that testCreatePdf is invoked before the testCreateHtmlFile. So, the answer you provided helped solve the issue. Thank you! :)